# Do I need to delete this object?

Tags: c++, mfc

In MFC application using Direct2D I have very simple code:
//in ctor:

```
EnableD2DSupport();
m_pBlackBrush = new CD2DSolidColorBrush(GetRenderTarget(), D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black));
```

Now the question is, am I supposed to call delete on m_pBlackBrush? If so where? I've tried to call delete on it in destructor but I'm getting error thrown in my face saying that there is write access violation. Anyone knows if am I supposed to delete this brush or simply leave it (which seems like rather odd idea)?

Comment: Sure you need to `delete` this object, when you created it using `new`, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: It may depend on how you use it. As I recall MFC had strange ideas about object ownership, so, like, if you put that brush in a device context, it might assume ownership. Sorry I don't recall the details.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Did you read my post? I've tried to call delete on it but I'm getting error, that's why I ask this question here

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf , yes, I believe that's what happening. Thanks a lot. Best regards.

Comment: You may work around the ownership issues by ensuring that at the end the brush is not selected in any device context or member of any other object collection. *Then*, just `delete` it.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando I can only read what's actually provided. You didn't mention a single character about what you're doing with that pointer further on. Just as your code snippet is, you have to `delete` the object yourself to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't have to mention what I'm doing with that pointer further on because the answer is in the line where the pointer is being initialized, that is in ctor of solid brush object. You expect sursplus info. Other don't and that's why they do get their answers right and you are a) giving incorrect answer (your very first comment) and b) expecting to be given information that is not really necessary to answer that question. See answer of #ZDF

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Well, many things are answerable. That doesn't make them good questions and helpful for future research per se.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ better to have not the best question, then completely no clue what the answer is and what's even worse, not realizing that you have all the information needed to answer that question and despite all of that at the end give completely **wrong** answer. As you did in your very first comment.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando My major critique about you (your questions) is that you're lazy in asking questions. You are using the Stack Overflow site like _let's go shopping_. _"I have a problem? OK, let's go to SO and throw it in, with least efforts on the question as possible."_ That attitude is a shame for such a long term member of the site.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not lazy, consise, but if you don't get it, am afraid that it is your personal problem.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando _"that it is your personal problem."_ I don't think so, check your question's score and close vote status.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't ask questions in order to get score. I ask them in order to get answers. In case you didn't get that either. But again, being quick doesn't seem to be your forte so I understand that you didn't get that either. Again, I put it into your personal problems shelf.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando I well, know that your strategy asking here is to get _quick answers_ for your personal concerns. But that doesn't lead to much more quality what resides in the repository. I wonder how you got managed not getting question banned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Happy wondering, again, another "my personal tragedy" example.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The question and close vote score may be a direct result of your (for whatever reason upvoted) first comment, that makes the question look useless. I would like to ask you again (this really is an annoying, recurring pattern with you) to comment on questions that are in your field of expertise. None of the comments and answer you gave on [tag:winapi] or [tag:mfc] questions, that I recall reading, where helpful or even correct. If you don't know the answer, just move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of this constructor is:

```
CD2DSolidColorBrush(
   CRenderTarget* pParentTarget,
   D2D1_COLOR_F color,
   CD2DBrushProperties* pBrushProperties = NULL,
   BOOL bAutoDestroy = TRUE
);
```

Notice the last parameter. From the MSDN ([CD2DSolidColorBrush::CD2DSolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg466833.aspx)):

> *bAutoDestroy*
>   Indicates that the object will be destroyed by owner (pParentTarget).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a little sample of Direct2D objects are working:

```
CChildView::CChildView() 
: m_pBitmamLogo(NULL), 
  m_pBrushBackground(NULL)
{
}

HRESULT CChildView::_LoadBackgroundBrush(CHwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget)
{
ASSERT_VALID(pRenderTarget);

// Create and load a Direct2D brush from a "PNG" resource
// NOTE: D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP repeats the brush's content
m_pBrushBackground = new CD2DBitmapBrush(pRenderTarget, // render target
    IDB_PNG_BACKGROUND,                                 // resource ID
    _T("PNG"),                                          // resource type
    CD2DSizeU(0, 0),
    &D2D1::BitmapBrushProperties(D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP, 
    D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP));

return m_pBrushBackground->Create(pRenderTarget);
}

CChildView::~CChildView()
{
// No need to free Direct2D resources
// because they are automatically destroyed by the parent render target 
}
```

Source:
http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/01/18/easy-png-resource-loading-with-mfc/

Comment: you don't have to call Create, but thank you for the example